# signature field in OpenOffice for handwriting on tablet, not a digital signature

Tags: openoffice-writer

I want to place a "signature field" in my OpenOffice writer-document.

I need this for the iOS/gPlay App ["PDF Forms"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.binarysolutions.fasp&hl=de) to sign PDF-Documents on touchscreens (handwriting/pen).

According to their FAQ I need a signature field in my OO-document - but even after some hours of research I still don't now, if OO offers such a field. I only find text-fields or digital signatures/certificates.

How can I add a signature to an OpenOffice writer document?

Answer (score 0):

it seems OpenOffice has just a subset of fields available, and the Signature Field isn't available.

What I'll do now is adding a textfield, naming it something like fldSignature1 and using iText i'll change every field starting with "fldSignature", programmatically, with a signature field

UPDATE:
here the code i'm using with success
as I said, i've created a form where i placed a textbox that act as a placeholder for the signature field, in my example i named it fldFirma, you can put the substitution code in a loop to change any field that contains a prefix, etc...

here the code

```
    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/testpdf.pdf";
    String filenameOut = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/testpdfCompiled.pdf"; 
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(filenameOut), '\0', true);
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();

    fields.setGenerateAppearances(true);

    String[] fieldsNames = (String[]) fields.getFields().keySet().toArray(new String[fields.getFields().keySet().size()]);
    for (String fieldName : fieldsNames) {
        if (fieldName.equals("fldFirma")) { //change this part with your logic to identify the signature field
            List<FieldPosition> fieldPositions = fields.getFieldPositions(fieldName);
            AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition = fieldPositions.get(0);
            // i remove the "placeholder field"
            fields.removeField(fieldName);

            // and place at its position, the new empty signature field
            stamper.addSignature(
                fieldName,
                fieldPosition.page,
                fieldPosition.position.getLeft(),
                fieldPosition.position.getTop(),
                fieldPosition.position.getRight(),
                fieldPosition.position.getBottom()
                );
        }
    }
    // close pdf stamper
    // stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

Comment: How do I use this code? I installed the iText jar on my Ubuntu computer, but can't figure out how to run this script....